# Which one is simpler between Ninject and StructureMap?

Tags: structuremap, ninject-2

I was wondering which one is simpler between Ninject and StructureMap ? Is there anything i should be aware when using them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, Ninject is probably easier to get started with if you've never done any DI before, but I've found StructureMap to be more extensible.

Whichever container you opt-for, try and follow the usual advice, and wrap it behind interfaces (not the little 'i') that you own. Embedding any 3rd party component deep into your code is usually asking for trouble.

At the end of the day, it's down to personal taste.

Comment: I can't see how it is possible to wrap it behind interfaces. You need to define his binding configuration in the MVC 3 config file.

Comment: Forget the wrapper interface, its not worth it. You shouldn't have calls to your container deep in your code anyway.